# Response from Docusign Powerform

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I am submitting a form that redirects to DocuSign and fills all the details in the PDF file. The user has to sign on the form. Once the user submits the form, it remains in the DocuSign page. Is there any way to redirect the user to my website there contains the link to perform? Is there any way to check the user has signed on the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible to set a redirect when a power form is completed, please have a look here: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-specify-a-URL-to-redirect-to-when-a-Powerform-is-completed

You can check who has signed on the form from within the "powerform" section in the ui.

Comment: Thank you Bendowlingtech. Let me check it and update you soon.

Comment: I have added the settings in the brand section, added URLs in the 'Configure Destinations' sections. Even after it is landing to a docusign page shows, 'You're All Done! You'll receive a copy once everyone has signed.'. How can I redirect to my website after a successful signing. I am using a test demo docusign account and the URL is my localhost URL eg:http://localhost/testdemo/. Can you please describe the 'Insert merge field' in it.

Comment: Hi Adam, is the branding being applied? Make sure "Set as Sign Default" is checked in the settings of the particular brand.

Comment: I have missed the checkbox, 'Set as Sign Default'. it is working!. Thank you so much :)